# Azure Cognitive Services icon for architecture diagrams

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am wondering if the new Cognitive Services icons are already able to be downloaded as I need to update my infographic on my blog to be up to date as well as do some architecture diagrams for my customers with the new icons. The image below should show, which icons I actually mean (you can find them on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/directory/vision/ as well)

[Azure Cognitive Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPVXC.png)

Comment: Some are here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41937

Comment: Hi, Thank you but I know these ones. But are there the new icons anywhere to find?

Comment: I don't know. BTW, please don't create duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545334/azure-cognitive-services-svg-icons